# TortioseSVN- How to share repsoitory between two disconneted computers?

Tags: tortoisesvn

Scenario: 2 developers working on the same project (VS2010, C#, MVC3, WinXP) on seperate stand alone computers. Due to IA restriction (DOD) we are NOT allowed to connect these two computers in any way. The only way we are allowed to pass data between computers is via a CD-R/DVD-R disk. We need to be able to share a SVN repository for the code we are writing. I'm trying to figure out what the best way to do this would be.

Will this scenario even work? What the best workflow to use? I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on the best way to do this.

Mark Buckley
putrtek@gmail.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me that you would be better off using distributed source control, such as Mercurial or Git for this project.  SVN makes it exceptionally hard to merge, and distributed source control would make it so that you just have to pass ChangeSets back and forth.

Also, distributed source control houses a repository on each system, which is what you would have to do in this situation anyways.

[This book](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/) should help you with most things Mercurial-related.
[This Link](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CommunicatingChanges) explains how to pull new ChangeSets into your repository.

Comment: The major problam I have is that these two compters are stand alone and not connected to ANY network at all, not even the Internet. So I need a solution that will work by passing data back and forth via a CDR-R/DVD-R disk.

Comment: This is exactly why distributed source control (DRCS) is perfect for this situation.  I'm going to talk in terms of Mercurial, because that's what I'm familiar with, but I know that Git is largely similar:

Mercurial stores a repository on each computer.  At the root of the directory under control, there is a ".hg" folder, which contains changes that you have committed.  When you want to exchange changes, the only thing you have to do is to write that folder to a CDR-R/DVD-R and transfer it.

Mercurial has great merging capabilities, so merging won't be a problem. Check out: http://hginit.com/

Comment: ok - That sounds like exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for the tutorial link I'll check it out. Appreciate your response.

Comment: ok I went thru the tutorial and I still having trouble understanding how this would work in my offline situation. The tutorial says to create a Central Repository then create a 'clone' of the repository which is used on my computer. How do I then get this clone over the my other developer's computer? Do I copy just the HG folder like you said or do I need the whole folder structure? Just trying to figure out the work flow here. Thanks again for your input.  -MARK-

Comment: Ok so on one the PC's I have a base VS 2010 propject setup. I have the directory structure the way I want it and I've addedd all the referances we want to use (Log4net, elmah, MVCcontrib, etc). I copied this project to a directory where I want my Central Repository to be. I've created the repository, Added and COmmittwed files to it. I then cloned the repository to a differant folder that will be my local working copy.  So what I need to figure out now is how do I go about getting this over to the other Developer's PC? What Files do I need to copy?

Comment: Cloning a repository is just a means of getting a full copy of the repository and the list of all changesets.  It's essentially just copying and pasting.  You really don't need a central repository, since they're generally meant for linking over a network.  But since you have one, we can consider that your master copy.  So what you need to do is transfer the entire directory containing your master repository over to the other PC.  After that, whenever you want to exchange changes, you can transfer them via disc and then use hg pull. Adding links to the main response (running out of room).

Answer (score 0):

In your situation I would propose the following scenario: setup and maintain SVN repository on the one selected PC (let's say the most reliable one), the other members pass CD-R's with patches when they finish part of work, then all patches are integrated in that SVN repo and for each members own patches are created to have similar code on each PC. I know, this sounds awkward, but maybe the best option in this case and operations with patches can be automatized.

Answer (score -1):

From a design perspective I think the code architecture needs to be good with clear separation of modules, less coupled codes, follow strict OOP, reduce code dependency and I guess in that way two people can easily work without much interaction... do plan your integration and do have your code / class signatures defined before hand if possible.